# How to trace a click on the stroke in Konva-react

Tags: react-konva, konva

Can you tell me how to track the click only on the stroke and not inside the body of the figure. The shapes in which you want to trace this can be anything: Star, Rect, etc. Perhaps you have encountered this.

I can't even imagine how it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw a shape with `fillEnabled: false` so only its stroke is visible. And only its stroke will listen to events. If you want to keep fill, then you have to use two shapes. One for fill, another for stroke and events detection.

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const shape = new Konva.Circle({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  radius: 50,
  stroke: 'green',
  strokeWidth: 10,
  fillEnabled: false
});
layer.add(shape);

shape.on('click', () => {
  console.log('shape click');
})
```

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^8/konva.min.js"></script>
  <div id="container"></div>
```